# How would FIDE handle a player with ADHD in tournaments?

Tags: rules, tournament, fide

I recently stumbled upon [Why is coffee provided during big chess events when it contains a banned substance?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/26505/why-is-coffee-provided-during-big-chess-events-when-it-contains-a-banned-substan/26508?r=SearchResults#26508) and learned that amphetamines are banned by FIDE.

How would FIDE handle a player with ADHD who is rightfully prescribed amphetamines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How would FIDE handle a player with ADHD who is rightfully prescribed
> amphetamines?

FIDE handles this in the same way as all Olympic sports handle such things. Anybody who follows such sports (particularly cycling) will be familiar with "Therapeutic Use Exemptions" or TUEs.

They are covered in the [FIDE Anti Doping Rules](https://handbook.fide.com/files/handbook/FIDEAntiDopingRules.pdf):

> **4.4 Therapeutic Use Exemptions (“TUEs”)**
> **4.4.1** The presence of a Prohibited Substance or its Metabolites or Markers, and/or the Use or Attempted Use, Possession or FIDE Anti-Doping Rules 14 Administration or Attempted Administration of a Prohibited Substance or Prohibited Method, shall not be considered an anti-doping rule violation if it is consistent with the provisions of a TUE granted in accordance with the International Standard for Therapeutic Use Exemptions.

FIDE provides a standard [Therapeutic Use Exemptions (TUE) Application Form](https://handbook.fide.com/files/handbook/TUE_application_form.pdf) which can be downloaded from their site, filled in, signed, and submitted.

Comment: Very correct. Chess is governed by the same anti-doping authorities that Olympians, cyclists and a number of other sports use. I use to have TUEs for sport when I was younger and competing in rock climbing, primarily asthma medication which is steroid based. TUE's are extremely common in sports (especially aerobic sports like cycling) that being said, it is an easy system to abuse. 

Regarding ADHD medication etc, simple TUE and you just declare your TUE's when get tested. I am unaware of any drug testing occurring in chess. That being said better to play by the rules than get caught ;)